# R: Selecting Rows based on values in multiple columns

Tags: r

I've a data frame which have many columns with common prefix "_B" e,g '_B1', '_B2',...'_Bn'.
So that I can grab the column names by:

```
allB <- c(grep( "_B" , names( my.df ),value = TRUE ) )
```

I wish to select the rows for which each of these _B* columns passes a single  condition like  values >= some_cutoff

Can someone tell how to do that, my efforts with 'all()' and 'any()' failed

```
set.seed(12345)     
my.df <- data.frame(a = round(rnorm(10,5),1), m_b1= round(rnorm(10,4),1),m_b2=round(rnorm(10,4),1))
allB <- c(grep( "_b" , names( my.df ),value = TRUE ) )
> my.df
     a m_b1 m_b2
1  5.6  3.9  4.8
2  5.7  5.8  5.5
3  4.9  4.4  3.4
4  4.5  4.5  2.4
5  5.6  3.2  2.4
6  3.2  4.8  5.8
7  5.6  3.1  3.5
8  4.7  3.7  4.6
9  4.7  5.1  4.6
10 4.1  4.3  3.8
```

I wish to select rows for which every m_b1 and m_b2 column is >= 4.0

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);my.df %>% filter_at(allB, all_vars(. >= cutoff))`  Please provide a small reproducible example with expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `filter_at` from `dplyr`, and specify `all_vars` (if all the values in the row meets the condition.  If it is any of the value in the row, it would be `any_vars`)

```
library(dplyr)
my.df %>%
   filter_at(allB, all_vars(. >= some_cutoff))
```

#### data

```
some_cutoff <- 3
my.df <- structure(list(`_B1` = c(1, 1, 9, 4, 10), `_B2` = c(2, 3, 12, 
 6, 12), V3 = c(3, 6, 13, 10, 13), V4 = c(4, 5, 16, 13, 18)), .Names = c("_B1", 
 "_B2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

allB <- grep( "_B" , names( my.df ),value = TRUE )
```

Comment: I'm having an error:

Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "filter_at"

I'm having dplyr_0.5.0, R version 3.3.0 on Win 7 64

Answer (score 1):

In base `R`:

```
some_cutoff = 4
selectedCols <- my.df[grep("_b", names(my.df), fixed = T)]
selectedRows <- selectedCols[apply(selectedCols, 1, 
                                   function(x) all(x>=some_cutoff)), ]

selectedRows
#   m_b1 m_b2
# 2  5.8  5.5
# 6  4.8  5.8
# 9  5.1  4.6
```

`grep()` is used to get the indices of columns with the pattern of interest, which is then used to subset `my.df`. `apply()` iterates over rows when the second argument, `MARGIN = 1`. The anonymous function returns `TRUE` if `all()` the entries match the condition. This logical vector is then used to subset `selectedCols`.

Comment: Thanks. tried something similar with apply(), but had some issues. Possibly the indices of columns was what I was missing

Comment: @TheAugust that's most likely it. Particularly, if you had a column of strings in the data.frame, the comparison `>= some_cutoff` would fail